# Layout XML "FINAL" Handle

Tags: layout, layout-update

A Magento installation that I'm working on has the [EM Quickshop](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/em-quick-shop-quick-view-product.html) module. In their `layout/em_quickshop.xml` file they have:

```
<quickshop_index_view>
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/> 
</quickshop_index_view>

<quickshop_index_view_FINAL>
    ...
```

In `<quickshop_index_view_FINAL>` they `<remove />` blocks that we want to keep. Probably just because "final" is such a common word, I'm having a hard time finding anything out about this. But what it seems is that `my_handle` get's loaded, and then `my_handle_FINAL` gets loaded, and nothing can come after that.

Therefore, the only way that I can see to un-remove the blocks that they are removing, is to edit their file directly. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Since they remove the blocks, it is indeed not really possible to solve this issue without copying the `layout/em_quickshop.xml` to your theme and change it there. There are some options though:

1. If you use the extension [Layout_Unremove by Alan Storm](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layout-unremove.html), you could unremove the blocks in your theme's `local.xml` with something like that:

   ```
   <x-unremove name="product.attributes"/>
   ```
2. You could re-define the blocks in your theme's `local.xml` like that:

   ```
   <quickshop_index_view_FINAL>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="my.product.description" as="my.description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
               <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
           </block>
       </reference>
   </quickshop_index_view_FINAL>
   ```